# How to use NSColor? Where does it belong? How to reference it?

Tags: ios

I want to use the keyboardFocusIndicatorColor inside my code but not sure where NSColor is. The documentation says AppKit.framework but when I try to link a library AppKit.framework does not exist.

```
NSColor *transBG = [[NSColor keyboardFocusIndicatorColor]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tagged this question iOS so you should be using UIColor and the UIKit framework instead.